# DHCP Client List include different IPs for the same MAC. Is it a bug?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp, wireless-access-point, mac-address

*Previously I tried to ask this on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) but they closed as off-topic. I relied on [this meta topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking) when posting there.*

I have an issue with [Netis N4](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) Wireless Router which looks like a bug to me.
[It is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W43Ee.png) from the router web interface which depicts the issue but I don't have enough reputation to inline it as an image.

After some time after router start up its DCHP Client List includes entries with duplicated MACs. For some reason router leases new IPs for the devices whose MAC is already in the lease table and creates another entry in the list.
When **Address Lease Time** was configured to 24 hours (86400 sec) every 1-2 days it resulted in "dhcpdiscover no address available". We have to reboot the router every 1-2 days to clean DCHP Client List.

For me, it looks like a bug. The same client (which means the same MAC) has to connect with leased IP if lease time for this client is not expired. If time is expired, the IP lease is dropped from the table.

Is it a bug or I confuse something about how DHCP works?
I tried researching with Google but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: What OS is the client running (and if it's Linux/BSD, which specific DHCP client software)?

Comment: Why do you think the issue is caused by the client's software? There are a bunch of different clients: smartphones with different OS and Windows machines.

Comment: Because standards-compliant DHCP servers actually distinguish leases by "Client ID" if it's present and only use the MAC address as fallback... And although _most_ DHCP clients will either send a MAC-based Client ID or none at all, there are certain DHCP clients which send a different ID type and get a distinct lease as a result despite still having the same MAC. (But that's mostly seen on Linux PCs – certainly not Windows nor any smartphone that I've seen.)

Comment: If it happens with various different clients I'd almost say it's a bug in the router... But, are you using anything like a wireless repeater or extender?

Comment: No, no repeater or extender. ISP - my router - clients.

Comment: Are you running virtual machines on a few clients?

Comment: @A.Loiseau No virtual machines.

Comment: Involved MAC address (in your screenshot) belongs to an Apple device. If you have only few of them you can try to track down the failing one. Maybe one of them is badly requesting new leases periodically. Also, network boots may cause extra leases to be asked by a device.

Comment: @A.Loiseau There are duplicated entries for other devices (Android, Windows) too. That's why I suspect a bug in router FW.